# Simple VB/SQL app and AZURE

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, azure

I have a simple ms sql 2012 express database & a simple VB Express 2010 application as its front end.

Can I simply host my MS SQL database on Azure & update the application to interrogate the hosted database? This would mean, the application would still be local, but the DB would be hosted. My offices are distributed & if we could do this it would save quite a bit of hassle.

Do I need to use a virtual machine, cloud services or straight hosting? Its difficult for me to understand the subtleties each service.

I've had a look at the azure services information and the documentation is pitched a little high for me. I just wanted to know if this is relatively simple thing to do & if anyone has has any pointers to How To's or Noob guides to azure.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely possible and in fact, super easy to set up.

Check out this simple step-by-step instruction on how to set up SQL Server DB on Windows Azure - https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/sql-azure-management/

You can even connect to it from your SQL Server Management Studio just like you would connect to a local database or a database on your network.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally - yes, you can change the connection string used by the VB desktop app to reference the Windows Azure SQL Database instance instead of the local database.  That said, SQL Database is not 100% compatible with SQL Server.  Be sure to check out the differences at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx

Comment: Thanks, its good to know the pitfalls, as there's always something :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I simply host my MS SQL database on Azure & update the application
>   to interrogate the hosted database?

Yes, your SQL Azure database is accessible via a connection string, but you have to make sure that you create a firewall rule in SQL Azure to allow your locally hosted or remotely hosted applications to access the database.  Everything is turned off by default.

> Do I need to use a virtual machine, cloud services or straight
>   hosting?

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but a VM may be overkill, as that gives you basically a place to host a VM in Azure.  You control the O/S, patching, etc.  A cloud service (a web or worker role) is a little less maintenance heavy as the O/S, patches, updates, etc. are maintained by Azure and you just worry about your application.  Straight hosting - are you talking about hosting on 1&1 or GoDaddy or something?  If so, that's really no different than your VB app running locally and accessing your Azure database.  For this option, just make sure you have your firewall rules set properly, otherwise you won't be able to access the database.

Hopefully this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Glad I could help.  A SQL Azure DB is really nice if you need a distributed DB solution.  Not that I do a lot with Excel, but I've had a SQL Azure DB be a data source for a Excel spreadsheet that I used a lot, and I had other processes (Console apps) that would update the data on a regular basis.  No hosting provider to deal with besides Azure.  It's a great business model.

Answer (score 0):

Azure has some specific requirements that need to be met (like every table has to have a Clustered Index), and it does not support some functionality that is available on "normal" SQL Server (like replication, FILESTREAM data, or data compression).

Other than that, as long as your app meets the requirements, there should not be a reason for it not to work on Azure. The majority of the functionality not supported by Azure is most likely out6 of the scope of what a "noob" would implement, so you probably are safe.

However, Azure might be overly expensive for your needs. It might be cheaper to go for hosting the database somewhere. This would mean you would only have to change the connection string of the application to point to the new database server (though there could be additional limitations imposed by your hosting provider).

Good luck with whichever option you end up taking!